# open an encrypted .xls file in java using apache poi api

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a file c:\code\aaa.xls. It has few cells empty. It is encrypted by password - pwd. I open the file by using java and apache poi, using Biff8EncryptionKey.setCurrentUserPassword("pwd");

I write data to it and save it in c:\new\1-aaa.xls (without password).

I empty the cells (to which I had written data) in aaa.xls, and save it with the same password - pwd. For that, I am using workbook.writeProtectWorkbook(Biff8EncryptionKey.getCurrentUserPassword(), "");

But, when I check the files, even 1-aaa.xls file gets the password and becomes read-only. I don't wan't that to happen. Users should be able to open 1-aaa.xls without password, but, aaa.xls should have the password - pwd.

Please guide me.

Comment: Why are you setting the write protect data on the file you don't want to have a password?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. If I provide the password, which i cannot share with any user, how will the document open? I want to open the document from software itself, by passing the password from the program. Then, few data is written to the file, it is saved in another location by a different name. Then, the original file's edited cells are cleared and saved with password.

Comment: please guide me...........

Comment: please somebody guide me.......

Comment: please please please guide me

Comment: somebody guide me please, waiting for a reply.........

Comment: I dont know how to proceed further, please somebody guide me!!!!!

Comment: no one to answer my question!!!

Comment: I think you may have mistaken StackOverFlow for a paid-for support forum... If this is super urgent for you, you might want to pay someone for a support agreement for your project on a suitable SLA!

Comment: Sorry, i had not asked in urgency. Since, last Thursday I had posted, I dint get any reply.

Answer (score 0):

Before you write to 'c:\new\1-aaa.xls', try to set password null:

```
Biff8EncryptionKey.setCurrentUserPassword("pwd");
```